# python pack output in string format

Tags: python, struct, pack

I have done the following.

```
from struct import pack, unpack
t = 1234
tt = str(pack("<I", t))
```

printing tt gives `\xf3\xe0\x01\x00`. How do I get original value of `t` back from tt?

I tried using unpacking the `repr(tt)` but that does not work out. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> t=1234
>>> tt=pack('<I', t)
>>> tt
'\xd2\x04\x00\x00'
>>> unpack('<I', tt)
(1234,)

>>> ttt, = unpack('<I', tt) 
>>> ttt
1234
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using the wrong package for serialization. the `struct` package is only useful for python code which interacts with C code.

for serialization into a string, you should use the [`pickle` module](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html).

```
import pickle

t = 1234
tt = pickle.dumps(t)
t = pickle.loads(tt)
```

Comment: Nobody mentioned serialisation. "Useful only for python code which interacts with C code"??? One uses `struct.pack` when writing binary files in some particular format and `struct.unpack` when reading them -- irrespective of what language may be used to read those files or may have been used to write those files originally. Using `pickle` instead of `cPickle` and using the default (text, ancient) protocol is a nonsense. Please consider deleting your answer.

Comment: @John Machin: although nobody mentioned serialisation, the title of the post implies serialisation, so i posted this answer as a hint that there exists a standard python way of serialising data. now regarding pickle/cPickle: starting with python 3, "the accelerated versions are considered implementation details of the pure Python versions. Users should always import the standard version"(from the [doc](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/whatsnew/3.0.html)). regarding the default protocol: pickle protocol version 3, which is now the default for python 3 and up, is indeed binary.

Comment: Real Programmers use Python 1.5.2

Comment: @John Machin: Real Programmers use languages that average programmers do not dare to use...

Answer (score 1):

`unpack('<I', tt)` will give you `(1234,)`.

`repr` doesn't work since it adds quotes to the string:

```
>>> repr('foo')
'"foo"'
```

Comment: unpack(tt) will give you an exception -- you need two arguments.